# How to fix “Field … required a bean of type … that could not be found” exception Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working with spring boot tutorial about @Autowired and @Primary annotation

 Below you can find my main class

```
package com.example.springtest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import service.Animal;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringtestApplication {
@Autowired
private Animal animal;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringtestApplication.class, args);

}

}
```

Animal interface (the interface that i should autowired)

```
package service;

public interface Animal {


      String characteristics();
}
```

Dog class (the primary implementation of Animal interface)

```
package service;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Primary
@Service
public class Dog implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String characteristics() {
        return "Bark";
    }
}
```

Cat class (the second implementation of Animal interface)

```
package service;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String characteristics() {
        return "Meow";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run the app there is a problem with injection of animal and I get following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field animal in com.example.springtest.SpringtestApplication required a bean of type 'service.Animal' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'service.Animal' in your configuration.
```

What could be the reason that Spring cannot do the autowiring?

Comment: Your Applicant class is not getting scanned. Either restructure your packages or add `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.xyz.something"})` or `@ComponentScan({"com.xyz.something"})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have created service class in different folder in place of the folder in which controller is present.

check the folder at least once.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add to your main class a `@ComponentScan` annotation, telling it to scan the package of the services, otherwise it will not initialize these beans

Comment: @LMA - it applies component scan on current package. Since his services are not located on the same package (or sub package) as the application class - it is required to set it explicitly

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration file will only pick up services that are in subpackages.

Your `SpringtestApplication` application is currently in the package `package com.example.springtest` This means that it will only autowire beans under that package. Ex `com.example.springtest.services`

However, it looks like your actual service `Dog` service is located in the package `service` so it will not be seen.

Try moving your services to `com.example.springtest.services`

Answer (score 0):

Spring will do a component scan under packages com.example.springtest.*. as your spring boot application is defined there and it acts as root of the application.

As you have defined your `Animal` interface, `Dog` and `Cat` service under
`service` package, Spring has no way to find out these beans and hence it can not autowire it.

Package hierarchy should like follows :

```
com
 --example
    --springtest
       -- service
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MockBean with Junit for testing controllers, be sure to add a mock bean of whatever dependency is reported missing on the log even if you might not be using it. Like  `@MockBean private BookService bookService;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32902958)